# jQuery image slider not showing content on IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery slider which swaps images and text, the problem I am having is that on IE7 and below I cannot get the slide content to appear above the images.

EXAMPLE (IE7):

[image: ie7]

(chrome)
[image: chrome]

This is the site: http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/index.php

I have tried altering the images and text `z-index` but that doesn't effect IE7. Is there any way of fixing this?

I also noticed that the arrows are missing as well.

EDIT:

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Ckde2/2/

Code:

HTML(part):

```
    <body id="home">
        <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
        <div id="content">
            <!-- BEGIN CONTENT TOP SLIDESHOW -->
            <div id="top-slide">
                <div class="wrapper">
                <!-- BEGIN CONTENT TOP SLIDESHOW SLIDES -->
                    <div id="slide0" class="slide" data:id="0">
                        <h2>Your Site... Defined</h2>
                        <h4>With D&amp;D there is no inbetween, we will never compromise your requirements.</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="slide1" class="slide" data:id="1">
                        <h2>Your Site... Defined 2</h2>
                        <h4>With D&amp;D there is no inbetween, we will never compromise your requirements.</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="slide2" class="slide" data:id="2">
                        <h2>Your Site... Defined 3</h2>
                        <h4>With D&amp;D there is no inbetween, we will never compromise your requirements.</h4>
                    </div>                     
                <!-- END CONTENT TOP SLIDESHOW SLIDES -->
                </div>
                <div id="slider-imgs">
                    <div id="s-img0" class="slide-imgs">
                        <img src="http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/slider/img1-g.png" id="s-img0-g">
                        <img src="http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/slider/img1-c.png" id="s-img0-c" class="color">                        
                    </div>
                    <div id="s-img1" class="slide-imgs">
                        <img src="http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/staff/profiles/directors/dpassmore/g.png" id="s-img1-g">
                        <img src="http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/staff/profiles/directors/dpassmore/c.png" id="s-img1-c" class="color">
                    </div>
                    <div id="s-img2" class="slide-imgs">
                        <img src="http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/staff/profiles/directors/dpassmore/g.png" id="s-img2-g">
                        <img src="http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/staff/profiles/directors/dpassmore/c.png" id="s-img2-c" class="color">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="numSlides">3</div>
                <div class="arrows">
                    <span class="arrow left"></span>
                    <span class="arrow right"></span>
                </div>
                <div id="select">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="bullets"></div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END CONTENT TOP SLIDESHOW -->
        </div>
</body>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //HOME.PHP
    $('#home #top-slide').bind("mouseenter", function() {
        $('#select').stop(true).fadeIn(600);
    });

    $('#home #top-slide').bind("mouseleave", function() {
        $('#select').stop(true).fadeOut(600);
    });

    //HOME.PHP - SLIDER

    function mainSlider() {
        var numsliders;
        var currentSlider = 0;
        var interval;
        var slideWidth;
        var slideImgWidth;
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();

        $('#slider0').css('opacity', 1);
        $(document).ready(function() {
            numsliders = parseInt($('#numSlides').html());
            generateBullets();
            checkHover();
            iefix();

            $('#slide0').css('left', '0px');
            $('#slide0').css('height', '300px');
            $('#slide0').css('width', '1000px');
            $('#slide0').css('top', '0px');
            $('#slide0').css('opacity', '1');

            $('#s-img0').css('opacity', '1');

            $('#slide0').addClass("showing");

            slideWidth = $('#slide0').width();

        });

        //arrow, bullet and autoplay functions

        function nextSlider() {
            specificSlider((currentSlider + 1) % numsliders);
        }

        function previousSlider() {
            if (currentSlider !== 0) {
                specificSlider((currentSlider - 1));
            }
        }

        interval = window.setInterval(nextSlider, 7000);

        function checkHover() {
            $('#home #top-slide').bind("mouseenter", function() {
                for (var b = 0; b < numsliders; b++) {
                    $(this).find(".slide-imgs img#s-img" + b + "-g").delay(300).fadeOut();

                    $(this).find(".slide-imgs img#s-img" + b + "-c").fadeIn(300);
                };
            });

            $('#home #top-slide').bind("mouseleave", function() {
                for (var d = 0; d < numsliders; d++) {
                    $(this).find(".slide-imgs img#s-img" + d + "-c").delay(300).fadeOut();

                    $(this).find(".slide-imgs img#s-img" + d + "-g").fadeIn(300);
                };
            });
        };

        function iefix() {
            for (var ie = 0; ie < numsliders; ie++) {
                $('#s-img' + ie).animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 0, null);
            };
        };

        function generateBullets() {
            var $bullet = $('#select .bullets');

            for (var i = 0; i < numsliders; i++) {
                $bullet.append('<span class="bullet" id="' + i + '"></span>');
            }

            $('.bullets #0').addClass("selected");
        }

        //call arrow functions
        $('span.arrow.left').click(function() {
            previousSlider();
        });

        $('span.arrow.right').click(function() {
            nextSlider();
        });

        //call bullet functions
        $('body').on('click', '.bullet', function() {

            var $id = $(this).attr("id");

            specificSlider($id);

        });

        function specificSlider(sliderNumber) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);

            // move the next slider on deck
            /*
            $('#slide' + sliderNumber).css('left', $('#top-slide').css('width'));
            $('#slide' + sliderNumber).css('top', '0px');
            $('#slide' + sliderNumber).css('height', '300px');
            $('#slide' + sliderNumber).css('width', '1000px');
            */

            // move old slide off, 
            $('#slide' + currentSlider).animate({
                left: '-1020px',
                top: '0px',
                height: '300px',
                width: '1000px',
                opacity: 0
            }, 900, null);

            $('#s-img' + currentSlider).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 900, null);

            $('#slide' + currentSlider).removeClass("showing");
            $('.bullets #' + currentSlider).removeClass("selected");

            // new slide on
            $('#slide' + sliderNumber).animate({
                left: '0px',
                height: '300px',
                width: '1000px',
                top: '0px',
                opacity: 1
            }, 900, null);

            $('#s-img' + sliderNumber).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 900, null);

            $('#slide' + sliderNumber).addClass("showing");
            $('.bullets #' + sliderNumber).addClass("selected");

            currentSlider = sliderNumber;

            interval = window.setInterval(nextSlider, 7000);
        }
    }

    //initalise slider 
    mainSlider();
});​
```

CSS(part):

```
/*============================================
    ENABLE FONTS
============================================*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700);

body {
    font-family:"PT Sans";
    font-size:13px;
}

html {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

/*============================================
    LINKS
============================================*/
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#CCCCCC;
    -moz-transition: color 150ms ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: color 150ms ease-out;
}

/*============================================
    LAYOUT
============================================*/
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#header .wrapper, #footer .wrapper {
    width:1100px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both !important;
    float:none !important;
}
/*============================================
    CONTENT
============================================*/
#content {
    min-height:100%;
    margin-top:55px;
    padding-top:10px;
}

/* IE FIX */
.ie7 #content {
    padding-top:65px;
}

/*============================================
    HOME.PHP
============================================*/
#home #content #top-slide {
    background:#3D3B37 url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/common/loaders/1.gif) no-repeat center;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#home #content #top-slide .slide {
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    left:-1000px;
    background:#3D3B37;
}

#home #content #top-slide .wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

#home #content #top-slide #numSlides{
    visibility: hidden;
}

#home #content #top-slide h2, #home #content #top-slide h4 {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    z-index:9999;
    display:block;
    zoom:1;
}

#home #content #top-slide h2 {
    margin:60px 0 0 0;
    font-size:36px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #1F1E1C;
}

#home #content #top-slide h4 {
    margin:150px 0 0 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #1F1E1C;
}

#home #content #top-slide .arrows {
    width:1100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}

#home #content #top-slide .arrows span.arrow {
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/arrows.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    height:36px;
    width:25px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:100;
    zoom:1;
}

#home #content #top-slide .arrows span.arrow.left {
    background-position:left;
    left:0;
}

#home #content #top-slide .arrows span.arrow.right {
    background-position:right;
    right:0;
}

#home #content #top-slide #select {
    height:48px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/bg-slie-select.png) repeat;
    display:none;
    line-height:48px;
    z-index:10;
}

#home #content #top-slide #select span.bullet {
    height:48px;
    width:25px;
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/bullets.png) no-repeat right;
    line-height:48px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#home #content #top-slide #select span.bullet:hover {
    background-position:center;
}

#home #content #top-slide #select span.bullet.selected {
    background-position:left;
}

#home #content #top-slide #slider-imgs .slide-imgs {
    position:absolute;    
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:9 !important;
}

#home #content #top-slide #slider-imgs .slide-imgs img {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    display:block;    
}

#home #content #top-slide #slider-imgs .slide-imgs img.color {
    display:none;
}

#home #content #twitter-main {
    background-color:#cccccc;
    height:200px;
    margin:10px 0;
    padding-top:30px;
    text-align:center;
}

#home #content #twitter-main i.icon-twitter {
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/common/social/twitter.png) no-repeat center;
    width:37px;
    height:37px;
    margin:0px auto 20px auto;
    display:block;
}

#home #content #twitter-main span.divider {
    border-top:1px solid #535353;
    height:0;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#home #content #twitter-main h2.feed {
    margin:40px 0;
}

#home #content #twitter-main p.info {
    font-size:10px;
    color:#666666;
}

#home #content #services {
    height:500px;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    background:#DDDDDD;
    padding-top:20px;
}

#home #content #services .wrapper > h2{
    margin-top:0px;
    font-size:24px;
}

#home #content #services .cols .col {
    margin:0 50px;
    float:left;
    width:233px;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/services-c-c.png) no-repeat top;
    height:260px;
    padding-top:170px;
}

#home #content #services .cols #ac.col {
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/services-c-ac.png) no-repeat top;
}

#home #content #services .cols #sup.col {
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/services-c-support.png) no-repeat top;
}

#home #content #services .cols #qu.col {
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/services-c-qu.png) no-repeat top;
}

#home #content #services .cols .col span.divider {
    border-top:1px solid #3D3B37;
    height:0;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: _"ie7 and below"_ ~  Below ie7?  Really?

Comment: You should include the relevant code within your OP, and also construct a jsFiddle demo of the bare minimum code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: i am doing a fiddle for you now :)

Comment: code and fiddle for everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!! By changing the wrapper's CSS:

```
#home #content #top-slide .wrapper {
    position:relative;
    z-index:9998;
}
```

Got the idea when i changed the arrow's container as well:

```
#home #content #top-slide .arrows {
    width:1100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9998;
}
```